# PowerShell get output in CSV format

Tags: powershell

I am seeking help to get output in csv format. I have written powershell code and would want to tweak the output to get in csv format as shown in below pic.

[image]

```
$servers = Get-Content 'C:\Temp\listofservers.txt'
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    #DHCP
    if (((Get-Service -ComputerName $server -ServiceName 'DHCPServer' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Status) -eq 'Running')
    {
        if ((((Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $server | Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName $server) | Measure-Object).Count) -ge 1)
        {
            Write-Host "DHCP present on $server and in use"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "DHCP present on $server and not in use"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host("DHCP is not present on $server")
    }
    #Certificate authority
    if (((Get-Service -ComputerName $server -ServiceName 'CertSvc' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Status) -eq 'Running')
    {
        Write-Host "Certificate Authority is present on $server"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Certificate Authority is not present on $server"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send all outputs to a custom object then export them:

```
$servers = get-content "C:\Temp\listofservers.txt"
$ExportPath = 'c:\temp\results.csv'

$Servers | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Checking $_"
    # DHCP status
    # Use Try....Catch to trap the errors - it's more robust than
    # If...Then and prevents a wall of red text if something goes wrong
    Try {
        $DHCPStatus = Get-Service -ComputerName $_ -Name 'DHCPServer' -ErrorAction Stop
        If ($DHCPStatus.Status -eq "Running") {
            Try {
                If ((((Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $_ -ErrorAction Stop | Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName $_ -ErrorAction Stop) | Measure-Object).Count) -ge 1) {
                    $DHCPResult = "DHCP present on, in use"
                }
                Else {
                    $DHCPResult = "DHCP present, not in use"
                }
            }
            Catch {
                $DHCPResult = "DHCP present - error obtaining details: $_"
            }
        }
    }
    Catch {
        $DHCPResult = "DHCP is not present"
    }
#Certificate authority
    Try {
        If (((Get-Service -ComputerName $_ -ServiceName 'CertSvc' -ErrorAction Stop).Status) -eq "Running") {
            $CAResult = "Certificate Authority is present"
        }
    }
    Catch {
        $CAResult = "Certificate Authority is not present"
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{ComputerName = $_;DHCP = $DHCPResult;CA=$CAResult}
} | Export-Csv -Path $ExportPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a hashtable to build your object, adding key/values for each property along the way.  Then convert the hashtable to a `[PSCustomObject]` and output it capturing in a variable (`$results`).  Finally, export it to csv using `Export-Csv`

```
$servers = Get-Content 'C:\Temp\listofservers.txt'
$results = foreach ($server in $servers) {
    # Create hashtable to build object and add ComputerName property
    $output = [ordered]@{ComputerName = $server }
    #DHCP
    if (((Get-Service -ComputerName $server -ServiceName 'DHCPServer' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Status) -eq 'Running') {
        if ((((Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $server |
                            Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName $server) |
                            Measure-Object).Count) -ge 1) {
            # add Dhcp property if present, in use
            $output.Add('Dhcp', 'Present, in use')
        }
        else {
            # add Dhcp property if present, not in use
            $output.Add('Dhcp', 'Present, not in use')
        }
    }
    else {
            # add Dhcp property if not present
        $output.Add('Dhcp', 'Not present')
    }
    #Certificate authority
    if (((Get-Service -ComputerName $server -ServiceName 'CertSvc' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Status) -eq 'Running') {
            # add CA property if present
        $output.Add('CA', 'Present')
    }
    else {
            # add CA property if not present
        $output.Add('CA', 'Not present')
    }
    # Convert hashtable to pscustomobject and output it
    [PSCustomObject]$output
}

# output results to screen
$results

# export results to csv file
$results | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\server_dhcp_ca_check.csv -NoTypeInformation
```